# MapReduce Frameworks That Call Reduce Once vs. 0...N Times

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce

The glued together word "MapReduce" is supposed to cover a generic concept (distinct from functional programming map/reduce), originating from a [conceptual paper from Google](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/mapreduce-osdi04.pdf).  It has an article on Wikipedia:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=MapReduce&oldid=1174612487) *(version at time of question)*

I think (?) the article is inconsistent in its examples.  This is possibly arising from some parts following a MapReduce definition used by the likes of MongoDB, and other parts following a definition used by systems like Hadoop.  I'd like to fix the article to make it consistent, and make note where the differences in interpretation apply.

Central to the confusion is about whether Reduce is called once per key (with an iterator of all the Map outputs for that key) or if it is called 0...N times, folding the results of prior Reduce calls to get to a single value.  The article gives a [type signature for Reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=MapReduce&oldid=1174612487#Logical_view) that does **not** enforce the outputs of Reduce as compatible with its inputs:

```
Map(k1,v1) → list(k2,v2)
Reduce(k2,list(v2)) → list((k3, v3))
```

That would seem to necessitate Reduce being called once (and only once) for a given key.  And I found a [Hadoop reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/hadoop/comments/42ydl0/getting_started_on_hadoop_can_somebody_explain/czexzjx/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) where someone says *"A reducer should be invoked once, and only once, for each key, and all values for that key should be passed together with it."*

But then the article [gives an example](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=MapReduce&oldid=1174612487#Examples) of calculating the average number of contacts someone has of a particular age on a social network:

```
function Map is
    input: integer K1 between 1 and 1100
           representing a batch of 1 million social.person records
    for each social.person record in the K1 batch do
        let Y be the person's age
        let N be the number of contacts the person has
        produce one output record (Y,(N,1))
    repeat
end function

function Reduce is
    input: age (in years) Y
    for each input record (Y,(N,C)) do
        Accumulate in S the sum of N*C
        Accumulate in Cnew the sum of C
    repeat
    let A be S/Cnew
    produce one output record (Y,(A,Cnew))
end function
```

...and it makes the claim that including C<sub>new</sub> in the output of Reduce is important to get a correct average:

> *"The count info in the record is important **if the processing is reduced more than one time**. If we did not add the count of the records, the computed average would be wrong."*

If Reduce is going to be called more than one time for the same key, then it must fold together with prior partial results.  This means it needs a more narrow type signature...designed for problems where the output of the reduce function is compatible with the input of the reduce function, so that it can be called repeatedly if necessary.  This is like the types given in the Google paper:

```
map(k1,v1) → list(k2,v2)
reduce(k2,list(v2)) → list(v2)
```

The example seems specifically crafted to match this case.  It's even able to skip the reduce step if you had only one value, because (N,1) has N as the trivial average for one person's contacts.  [MongoDB seems to have this behavior of not running reduce on a single record.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11022062/9308986)

If my understanding is correct, systems like MongoDB would require C<sub>new</sub> as output from Reduce in order to guarantee an accurate average--since it does not a priori know how many calls to reduce will be made for the same key.  Hadoop would not need to output C<sub>new</sub>, due to Reduce being called once-and-only-once per key and producing the complete average in one call.  (Otherwise unmerged average output records would be made from the same key, so scenarios like averaging would not run to completion in Hadoop.)

So the article would need to be updated somehow to reflect these points.

Comment: "designed for problems where the output of the reduce function is compatible with the input of the reduce function, so that it can be called repeatedly if necessary"

This isn't always (or even occasionally) true, which probably clears up the rest of your question. As you point out, averaging doesn't work like this, nor do ranking algorithms.

Comment: I'm talking about Hadoop MapReduce and not MongoDB. Averaging and ranking do work in Hadoop MapReduce which is arguably the most generalised MapReduce implementation there is (being the direct output of the whitepaper).

Comment: Look into `combiners` which do more like what you're talking about https://www.tutorialspoint.com/map_reduce/map_reduce_combiners.htm

Comment: I'm not sure why this is tagged Mongo and Hadoop. They work differently. Scala/Haskell also have map and reduce functions, so are you really asking about distributed processing and idempotent jobs?